# Table Maintenance on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

I was hoping to be able to do some Optimization on my MySQL Google Cloud instance.  When I attempt to use MySQL Workbench to execute optimization on a table I receive:

Unhandled exception: ('Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation', 1227)

Unfortunately I do not know where this 'SUPER' is coming from.  I am access the DB as Root.

Assistance is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench is excuting an operation/command that requires SUPER privileges [1] . Unfortunately, you can't get SUPER priviliges in CLoud SQL due to its security restrictions [2].

You must identify with instruction is causing this so you can report it on the Cloud SQL public issue tracker [3] although, relaxing security restrcitions is hihgly unlikely. Alternatively, you can report it on MySQL [4].

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction#features

[3] https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list

[4] http://bugs.mysql.com/

Comment: Thanks this seems like what is at issue ... Any recommendation on how to do maintenance on tables given this restriction?

Comment: Not an expert on DB administration, probably you can get some help on the [Google Groups of CLoud SQL](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sql-announce)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you authorised your IP address in the Add Authorised Network and also try changing the password in the Google Instance of the database.

Comment: That is not the issue connection is fine

Comment: I have been using [SQLyog] (https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) for connecting to my instances on Google Cloud.. It works fine without any problem. What is the optimisation that you are trying to do on the table?